# The name "Navigation" does not exist in the current context (MAUI)

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

This is the view model file:

```cs
public partial class LoginViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    void Login()
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage()); // <== The name `Navigation` does not exist in the current context
    }
}
```

Why `Navigation` can't be accessed in view model files, but can be accessed in `.xaml.cs` files?

Comment: Navigation is a property on the view. Are you using Shell or NavigationPage? (Shell is default on maui). If using Shell, read Maui Shell Navigation doc.

Comment: As ToolmakerSteve pointed out, only Views inherit the `Navigation` property. As a general rule, I would recommend to not perform any navigation directly in your ViewModel anyway, because that usually breaks the MVVM pattern by creating a dependency on the View. You should hide navigation behind an interface and perform navigation in the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using shell, you can check document [.NET MAUI Shell navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0).

Shell includes a URI-based navigation experience that uses routes to navigate to any page in the app, without having to follow a set navigation hierarchy. In addition, it also provides the ability to navigate backwards without having to visit all of the pages on the navigation stack.

Of course, if you indeed need to navigate on your ViewModel, you can try to pass the `Navigation` through the VM Constructor. Since pages inherit from `VisualElement`, they directly inherit the Navigation property.

```
public  class LoginViewModel 
{
    public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }

    public ICommand ContinueBtnClicked { get; set; }

    public LoginViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        this.Navigation = navigation;
        this.ContinueBtnClicked = new Command(async () => await GotoNextPage());
    }


    public async Task GotoNextPage()
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new NextPage());
    }
}
```

**LoginPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp210.LoginPage"
             Title="LoginPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />


        <Button  Text="Navigate" Command="{Binding ContinueBtnClicked}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**LoginPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage 
{
      public LoginPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BindingContext = new LoginViewModel(Navigation);
      }
}
```

Comment: That's breaking the MVVM pattern, the ViewModel shouldn't know about Pages. A cleaner solution would have been to hide the navigation behind a different interface which abstracts away the dependency on the Pages.

Comment: I understand that this deviates from the MVVM pattern, but is there an alternative method to extract the Navigation object of the ContentPage? We could potentially abstract the Navigation object from the MainPage using:

Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation

However, it doesn't exhibit the same behavior as the Navigation object of the ContentPage.